# select rows based on certain conditions with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to return the rows which has all columns > 0 or where only 2012 can be < 0.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame( {
   'A': ['d','d','d','f','f','f','g','g','g','h','h','h'],
   'B': [5,5,6,7,5,6,6,7,7,6,7,7],
   'C': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
   'S': [2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2012,2013]     
    } );

df = (df.B + df.C).groupby([df.A, df.S]).sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
```

@jezrael, not exactly. I changed the dataframe to explain better. In the final result I need the rows where all columns are > 0 AND the ones where the columns are > 0, except for 2012. That one can be < 0. The result must show a new df with the columns that qualify. So, in the example below, g yes, d no.

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {
   'A': ['d','d','d','d','d','d','g','g','g','g','g','g'],
   'B': [5,5,6,-7,5,6,-6,7,7,6,-7,7],
   'C': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
   'S': [2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2012,2012,2014,2015,2016,2012,2013]     
    } );

df = (df.B + df.C).groupby([df.A, df.S]).sum().unstack(fill_value=0)

S  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016
A                              
d    13     6     7    -6     6
g   -11     8     8     8     7
```

EDITED Dataframe;

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {
   'A':  ['d','d','d','d','d','d','g','g','g','g','g','g',
    'k','k','k','k','k','k'],
   'B': [5,5,6,7,5,6,-6,7,7,6,-7,7,-8,7,-6,6,-7,50],
   'C': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
   'S':   [2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2012,2012,2014,2015,2016,2012,
        2013,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2014]     
    } );

df = (df.B + df.C).groupby([df.A, df.S]).sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)

S  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016
A                              
d    13     6     7     8     6
g   -11     8     8     8     7
k    -6     9     48     8    -5
```

Comment: '_where only 2012 can be < 0_' err, _what_?? 2012 is greater than zero

Comment: column 2012:
df = (df.B + df.C).groupby([df.A, df.S]).sum().unstack(fill_value=0)

Comment: yes and nothing is negative in that column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use double mask one for compare rows and one for columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {
   'A': ['d','d','d','f','f','f','g','g','g','g','h','h','h', 'f'],
   'B': [5,5,6,7,5,6,-6,7,7,7,6,7,7,2],
   'C': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
   'S': [2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2012,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2012,2013,2013]     
    } );

df = (df.B + df.C).groupby([df.A, df.S]).sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
S  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016
A                              
d     6     6     7     0     0
f     7     3     0     8     6
g    -5     8     8     8     0
h     8     8     0     0     7
```

```
mask1 = df[2012] < 0
print (mask1)
A
d    False
f    False
g     True
h    False
Name: 2012, dtype: bool

mask2 = (df > 0).all()
print (mask2)
S
2012    False
2013     True
2014    False
2015    False
2016    False
dtype: bool

print (df.loc[mask1, mask2])
S  2013
A      
g     8
```

---

```
print (df[mask1])
S  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016
A                              
g    -5     8     8     8     0

print (df.loc[:,mask2])
S  2013
A      
d     6
f     3
g     8
h     8
```

EDIT by edit of question:

```
mask1 = df[2012] < 0
print (mask1)
A
d    False
g     True
Name: 2012, dtype: bool

mask2 = (df.drop(2012, axis=1) > 0).all(axis=1)
print (mask2)
A
d    False
g     True
dtype: bool

print (df[mask1 & mask2])
S  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016
A                              
g   -11     8     8     8     7
```

Comment: mask1 brings me all rows with negative values, but also other columns which are negative. These need to be positive, so 2012 can be -, but then the others need to be +. 

Or all columns positve, but mask2 shows that

Comment: sorry, I dont explain it. So `mask1` compare only column `2012` if less as `0` and `mask2` first remove column `2012` and then compare if all values in all column are higher as `0`. Then both masks are used with `&` to [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). Am I something missing?

Comment: nope, you're not. I missed a negative in another column and got an empty df. I checked and it works, thanks. btw, if want to add another criteria, the total of years per row need to be let's say > 20 ('g' won't show then). can I solve that with a mask?

Comment: I think then need `mask3 = df.sum(axis=1) > 20` and `print (df[mask1 & mask2 & mask3])` or `print (df[(df[2012] < 0) & ((df.drop(2012, axis=1) > 0).all(axis=1)) & (df.sum(axis=1) > 20)])`.  I think you can check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#building-criteria), it explain better as me.

Comment: think we're close, however, rows with all columns positive don't show

Comment: Hmmm, all condition return `True` at least in one row? Maybe such data are not in `DataFrame`. Small advice - first try test small sample `DataFrame` with small int numbers and if it works perfect, then use solution for real big data. I have no your real data, so it is hard find problem.

Comment: I've edited the df, when I run : print (df[(df[2012] < 0) & ((df.drop(2012, axis=1) > 0).all(axis=1)) & (df.sum(axis=1)  I get an empty df. I need 'd' and 'g' to show

Comment: ok, but then need in first column `2012` in row `d` change `13` to `-13`, right?

Comment: no, I want rows with all columns positive AND all rows where 2012 is negative and 2013, 2014, 2015 and 2016 are positive

Comment: yes, I know, but that is not what I want. Like I stated in the original question; rows with all columns positive AND the ones where 2012 is negative, but the rest positive. so row 'd' and 'g' is the example.

Comment: Hmmm, but then need `or` `|` (first OR second condition) AND third condition, with all `AND` it is impossible. So try `df_without_2012 = df.drop(2012, axis=1)` and

`print (df[((df[2012] < 0) | (df_without_2012 > 0).all(axis=1)) & (df_without_2012.sum(axis=1) > 20)])`

Comment: close, the columns being positive (or even with 2012 negative) take precedence over the row total > 20. I've edited the df to reflect that. 'k' shouldn't be returned.

Comment: I swap conditions `print (df[((df[2012] < 0) | (df_without_2012.sum(axis=1) > 20)) & (df_without_2012 > 0).all(axis=1)])`

Comment: great, that works. Thanks! btw, would it be possible to use a generic reference for column 2012, so I don't have to change code in the future? something like first column of dataframe; df_without_first column = df.drop(first column, axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

Combine the operators and use parentheses:

```
df[((df > 0).all(axis=1)) | (df[2012] < 0)]
Out[22]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]
Index: []
```